# How to remove title of inline object in django admin UI

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

As you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDlPK.png) ,there is an image, there is one 1st model (1st mentioned in image), 2nd model is inlined one. Just wanted to remove the 2nd model title(which is highlighted by red color, complete row I want to delete

```
class NewmodelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
    extra = 1
    model = Newmodel


@admin.register(Test)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    delete_cache_keys_for_model = 'Test'
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (
                'name',
                'age',
                'lastmod',
            ),
        }),
        ('Numbers', {
            'fields': (
                'test1',
                'test2',
            ),
        }),
    )
    form = TestForm
    inline_type = 'stacked'
    inlines = [NewmodelInline]
```

with the help of above code generated a form attached in the image.

Now just wanted to remove the title from the admin UI, as attached in image(whole row highlighted with red color and text as 2nd)